# How to overclock a laptop

Tags: debian, cpu, overclocking, intel

I have a linux laptop with debian on it(with i5 8250u). in the [intel introduce site for i5 8250u](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124967/intel-core-i58250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html) it says it support TDP-UP , I wonder how to set the TDP on this debian. Or even better maybe overclock it

If somebody acually solve it, it will be really usfull to all the people

hardware: i5 8250u
ddr4 8gb
128gb ssd
intel UHD 620 igpu
fan for cool
system: this is basically a chromebook with debian enviroment on it.
it does not have a real bios
the cpu support tdp-up from 15w to 25w(1.6Ghz to 1.8Ghz)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No laptop or PC newer than 2012 have BIOS, they all have UEFI, not that it matters much for the question. The question is unanswerable as it is now. It can be improved by [edit]ing and adding hardware specifications and OS version. That said, there's probably no way to do it outside of the firmware (laptops typically DON'T have OC enabled settings) and/or some proprietary software that no chance to exist for Linux.

Comment: I aded some more detail about the system, I really don't understand what detail I need to  add, please tell me what information is needed

Comment: Your processor doesn’t directly support overclocking. So you can eliminate that goal. It will, as explained by the numerous duplicates to your other question, increase and decrease it’s own frequency within its thermal limits but you won’t be able to raise what the base frequency or the boost frequency is by overclocking your processor

Comment: what about TDP-UP?

Comment: Have you think about the heat balance in this machine. Who will cool these 10 Watts? And I do not see much sense, you increase power by 60% to get 12% of frequency...

Comment: What about increase the tdp? I'm sure I can do that, but does that increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

Laptops are not intended to be overclocked, and therefore do not support the functions necessary to overclock.

Laptops have a finite amount of cooling capability. They are engineered to balance the cooling capabilities of the physical design with the performance of the hardware, and so changing the hardware's power consumption and generated heat would go beyond the laptop's capabilities and damage would result.

For this reason the settings and components are not offered to support overclocking.